# How to get Landsat 7 Land Surface Temperature

Tags: landsat-7, land-surface-temperature

I am working on Landsat 7 Level 2, Collection 2, Tier 1 images through the Google Earth Engine to calculate the land surface temperature in NYC. Can I use the values of band 6 as land surface temperature? Or do I need to do some calculations with the band values to get the proper land surface temperature?

Comment: Landsat Collection 2 Surface Temperature  https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-collection-2-surface-temperature

Answer (score 1):

Just answered this myself:

From page 3 of [Landsat 7 ETM Format Control Document](https://d9-wret.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/palladium/production/s3fs-public/media/files/LSDS-1337_Landsat7ETM-C2-L2-DFCB-v6.pdf)

```
The ST band is scaled to Kelvin by multiplying the DN times the value for
TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B6 and adding the value for
TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B6. All values can be found in Table 3-4
```